# Can't get pluralize/singularize working with ActiveSupport::Inflector (in irb)

Tags: ruby, activesupport

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'active_support'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'active_support/inflector/inflections'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize('test')
=> "test"
irb(main):004:0> ActiveSupport::Inflector.singularize('tests')
=> "tests"
irb(main):005:0> ActiveSupport::Inflector.titleize('hat simulator')
=> "Hat Simulator"
<ort::Inflector.tableize("america's number one hat simulator")
=> "america's number one hat simulator"
```

Well, basically, that's the question. It's confusing me that methods such as `titleize` seem to work fine, but `tableize`, `pluralize` and `singularize` don't.

Have I forgotten to require something?

(On a separate note, I notice [this page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) provides examples like `"post".pluralize`, which when I tried, resulted in `NoMethodError: undefined method 'pluralize' for "post":String`. But maybe that's something to save for another question.)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Access to `#pluralize` without adding new methods to the `String` class:

```
require 'active_support/inflector'
ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize('test')
#=> "tests"
```

For `String` class:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string'
"test".pluralize
#=> "tests"
```

which actually calls `ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize` underneath:

```
def pluralize
  ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize(self)
end
```

Comment: This worked for me but I was curious if having to include helpers within your controller is a sign of a particular code smell? I feel like I shouldn't have to do all this...